# Django-facebook: how to repost to a group or fanpage

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, django-facebook

Please help, I'm not familiar with facebook API.

I have a facebook app with a token and secret.
My users are happily authenticated via `python-social-auth`.
I've installed `django-facebook`.

I want to create a group (or a fanpage) and make my content automatically reposted to facebook on `model.save()`

How do I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Art&Logic blog with their [Tutorial: Posting to Facebook from a Django App](http://www.artandlogic.com/blog/2014/04/tutorial-posting-to-facebook-from-a-django-app/). I think that's exactly what you're looking for.

They use `facebook-sdk` instead of `django-facebook`, though.